# Send form data via email on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, parsing

I have a form that submits data to parse.com using the code below:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxxxx");
    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("Event");
    var testObject = new TestObject();
    testObject.save({
       Name: document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value, 
       Date: document.forms["myForm"]["date"].value,
       success: function(object) {
         $(".success").show();
       },
       error: function(model, error) {
         $(".error").show();
       }
    });
}

</script>
```

however I was wondering if there was a way that I could simultaneously send an email with the contents of the form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would need some type of server side script to send email.

If you use PHP, you could use the [`mail`](http://php.net/mail) function.

In the JavaScript, you would just send an AJAX request to the server-side file containing the code that sends the email.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, use AJAX to send it. Here's an example code:

JavaScript

```
var name = "Test";
var last_name = "Last Test";

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"your_php_file.php",
    data:{
        name : name, 
        lastname : last_name
     },
    success:function(data){
        // TODO when success
    }
});
```

And your PHP file would look like:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
```

Note i've used different last name's on purpose.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, once in PHP you can send email either by using mail, PHPMailer or whatever you wish